# Eclipse dark theme on mac

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, ide

I changed Eclipse's theme to dark and adjusted the font size.
After restarting Eclipse the colors are different and the font size is default. In settings the theme still set to dark, and it shows my custom font size. What's causing this?

Comment: It isn't entirely clear what you mean, what are you asking?

Comment: It could be your grammar...

Comment: I edited it for you. I'm assuming English isn't your first language. Still, if someone doesn't understand you, you should try re-explaining instead of yelling at them. Clear communication is the responsibility of the person speaking.